# Graphing Data for WFA in flow charts: searchin for .NET library

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a process flow chart out of my c# code. A user should be able to enter data such as type of element and connections to other elements and I want my code to create a flow chart out of it.
I also write the data into a .csv file. The Data is in the form of "ElemwntTitle, ElementType, Connections".

[image: Mock up of the desired flow chart with only one type of element]

This chart should:

- connect the elements
- place the elements in a way that is readable
- change form/color of the elements according to its type
- be saveable as a .png or .jpg file

I am looking for a useful .NET package but so far I've only been able to find stuff to create programming diagrams (class diagrams etc.) that visualize my code.

Ideally the package is understandable to a mediocre c# programmer. I'm new in creating visual things with my code as I usually program hardware.

In case it's relevant: I use visual studio and am creating a Windows Forms App for the user to insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [**GoDiagram 10**](https://godiagram.com/winforms/latest/samples/), which we (Northwoods Software) recently released into beta.

**GoDiagram 10** includes templating for nodes and links, data-binding, a JSON model data format, animation, and many more features. You can certainly create process flow diagrams with it, and it covers all your requirements.